# .parse().expect("err") panics instead of handling a parse error

Tags: error-handling, rust

I am working my way through [the Rust guessing game tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) and am stuck. The tutorial states that

```
let mut guess = String::new();
let guess = "asdf";
let guess: u32 = guess.trim().parse().expect("err");
```

parses a `String` and `expect` evaluates the `Result` and stops in case of an error. So the output should be `err`, but I get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'err: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', libcore/result.rs:945:5
```

I am using Rust stable.

Why doesn't my expect catch the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *did*.  If you change the `expect` message to `"oh no i am asploded"`, this is the output:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'oh no i am asploded: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', libcore/result.rs:945:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

`expect` is just `unwrap` with a custom message, and `unwrap` panics if it's used on a `None` or `Err(_)`.

As for handling errors without panicking, you'll need to read the section on [Recoverable Errors with `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) in the book.

Comment: oh! so the only case of `expect` is to add some debug information to the panic? so the proper way to handle the error is to ```match guess.trim().parse::<u32>() {...}``` ?

Comment: @KuSpa: I've amended my answer.